# Accessing Information from a SQL Dataset

Tags: sql-server, dataset, datasource

I have recently started working with SQL databases of which I have no previous experience with. I have added the datasource to my project using the Visual Studio wizard and the DataSet appears in my solution explorer.

Everything that I have read thus far has shown connecting to the SQL server and then sending query commands, but since I have added the direct reference to my project is this necessary. I thought since I had added the reference to my project I would have direct accesbility to it, but it appears that is not so.

Also to help the searching process a view has been created on the SQL server that polls all of my desired fields in a single shot.  I have linked this view to my dataset after utilized the datasource wizard. Any recommendations on how I can access the data from that view?

I apologize for the vagueness of my questions, but I am not really 100% sure the questions I need to be asking. I appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the best means to solve this problem was to ditch the Data Source Wizard and use standard SQL queries.